# Set row/column/block to 0 in Eigen sparse matrix?

Tags: eigen

I see with new Eigen 3.2, you can get row, column or even block from a sparse matrix, is there a way to set any of these to 0?

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> A( 5, 5 );
    A.block(1, 1, 2, 2) = 0; // won't work
    A.row(1) = 0; // won't work
    A.col(1) = 0; // won't work
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want exactly? replace the non-zeros by explicit zeros? fill the row with explicit zeros? remove all non-zeros? And then what do you want to do afterwards? keep it empty? fill it with new values? and finally, wouldn't it be faster to simply remove the row/columns?

Comment: Hi ggael, I would like to remove all non-zero entries for that row/column, but not the row/column itself, because I still need the matrix to be 5 x 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 5x5 matrices, it is overkill to use a sparse matrix. Better use a `MatrixXd`, or even a `Matrix<float,5,5>`. In this case you can set a row to zero with `A.row(1).setZero()`. Sparse matrices are worth it for matrices of size about 1000x1000 and greater.

Anyway, the best to suppress multiple columns and rows of a sparse matrix at once is to use the prune method. Here is an example removing the second row and third column:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> A;
  A = MatrixXf::Random(5,5).sparseView();
  A.prune([](int i, int j, float) { return i!=1 && j!=2; });
  std::cout << A << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The 5,5 matrix is just an example for the question and testing. Thanks for the information on prune.

Comment: ggael, I wonder if this prune function will iterate over every (i,j) in the matrix? It it does, seems this will cause a performance issue for large matrix.

Comment: It only iterates over the non zeros. If you want to remove a column of a column major matrix, then that's overkill, but for removing one row of a column major matrix, then this strategy is not too bad because the number of non zeros per column is assumed to be small and so a linear search won't be much slower than a binary search (and that's even better if you remove multiple rows).

Comment: I agree. Depending on how many column elements in a row major matrix, pure iteration and binary search will perform differently. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @ggael So what is the canonical way of removing column in column major matrix? Or rather setting it zero.

Answer (score 1):

Eigen's Tutorial for sparse matrices ([Tutorial Sparse: block operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#TutorialSparse_SubMatrices)) explain that for ColumnMajor (resp. RowMajor) sparse matrices, the column (resp. row) sub-matrix operators have write-access.

So, for example, to set to zero the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows of a rowmajor sparse matrix you could do:
`Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> A;
A = MatrixXf::Random(5,5).sparseView();
A.middleRows(1,3) = Eigen::SparseMatrix<float,Eigen::RowMajor>(3,A.cols());`

And leave `prune()` for setting to zero columns of row major matrices and vicevesa.

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, the simplest way set to zero a row/column/block is just to multiply  it by 0.0.

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> A;

A = MatrixXf::Random(8,8).sparseView(); //Initialize to random values

A.block(1, 1, 2, 2) *= 0; //Set a block to 0
A.row(1) *= 0;            //Set a row to 0
A.col(1) *= 0;            //Set a column to 0

std::cout << A << "\n";
```

Using prune() to set a block to zero can be faster if the density of your sparse matrix is high, but for most cases `*= 0`is quite fast and you don't have to rewrite your code depending of RowMajor/ColMajor ordering.

If you are really interested in free memory after setting the row/col to 0, just add a `A.prune(0,0)` after you have finished editing the matrix.